# Removing page number from ToC while maintaining header/footer information

Tags: table-of-contents, header-footer, page-numbering

I am editing a document that was created by someone else.  The original document has a custom header/footer and the page numbering was commented out.  All I wanted to do was to turn the page numbering on.  I figured out how to do that, however, in doing so, the ToC (which also uses the header/footer) now shows page numbering as well. The document has a cover page, a blank page, a title page, then the ToC.  Because I don't care to show the header/footer on the first 3 pages, I can use the `\thispagestyle{empty}` command and thus not show any page numbers.  However, I do want to maintain the header footer information (minus the page numbering) in the ToC.  FYI, the ToC itself is 6 pages long.  The page numbering on the first page of the ToC starts with page 4.  How can I suppress the page numbering on all 6 ToC pages while still maintaining the rest of the header/footer information?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. You need to define a new page style for the ToC. How this is done depends on your document setup, so please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Answer (score 3):

If you only want to remove page numbers for the first segment of your document while leaving the rest of your header/footer unchanged, redefine `\thepage` to display nothing at the start of your document and restore its original definition after the first segment (and a page break).

```
\documentclass{article}

\pagestyle{headings}

\begin{document}
\renewcommand*{\thepage}{}

\tableofcontents

\clearpage
\renewcommand*{\thepage}{\arabic{page}}

\section{foo}

\subsection{foobar}

Some text.

\end{document}
```